# Javascript - multiple regular expression in split method

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

```
'i-love_sushi_andNoodles'.split(/[-_ ]/);
'i-love_sushi_andNoodles'.split(/(?=[A-Z])/);
```

Basically, I want to combine above two logics as one. and expect results as

```
["i", "love", "sushi", "and", "Noodles"]
```

I feel like there must be easy way to do this.
Please help me out

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
console.log('i-love_sushi_andNoodles'.split(/[-_ ]|(?=[A-Z])/));
```

Comment: `|` == or ? ah yeah!!